# HTML search to PostgreSQL db syntax "$" error

Tags: php, html, postgresql, forms

I want create php file that show a db all row's, i look at the internet but there "$" is syntax error, and other variable i didn't find.

Here's my php code :

```
    if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
$searchq = $_POST['search']; };


$query = 'SELECT * FROM serviss WHERE pasutijuma_nummurs =$searchq ';
```

I tried put in

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM serviss WHERE pasutijuma_nummurs ='·$searchq' ';
```

But query didn't work at all.

And here's my HTML form:

```
<form action="search.php" method="POST">
 Meklēt pēc pasūtijuma nummura  <input type="text" name="search ">
 <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
</form>
```

I hope someone can help me.

**Fixed that problem**  :

```
$result = pg_query($db, "SELECT * FROM serviss where pasutijuma_nummurs = '$_POST[search]'");
```

Comment: Enable error reporting. Your form failed because of the input having a space in it; it counts.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `;` at the end of `if` statement. And double quote your query.

```
if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
    $searchq = $_POST['search'];

    $query = "SELECT * FROM serviss WHERE pasutijuma_nummurs = '$searchq'";
}
```

**Do not forget to use [prepared statements](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/sql-prepare.html).**

Comment: Well it didn't work or mby i'm just doing wrong.

Comment: What error are you getting now? Be sure `$_POST['search']` is set.

Comment: i put an code in the "Answer yourself"

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM serviss WHERE pasutijuma_nummurs = '{$searchq}'";
```

But first you need validate your data.
Hope help you.